# How to check if a specific block of text is present in a file using Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible to automate some tasks when installing some applications.

In some point, I want to check if in a file, some lines are present. In the file are several lines always in the same order with the same content. And I want to check that no extra lines appear inserted between the previous lines.

I think that the correct command is `blockinfile`, mixed with `state: present` to assure that the lines are there. Also I use `check_mode` to not change the file. Then the task is:

```
- name: Check content of file
  delegate_to: localhost
  blockinfile:
    dest: "{{ file.path }}"
    block: 
      line 1 text....
      line 2 text....
      line 3 text....
    state: present
  check_mode: yes
```

But, the task does not fail neither if the block is present or not. And Ansible continues without stopping. As suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43872222/1165160). I can add `failed_when` as:

```
- name: Check content of file
  delegate_to: localhost
  blockinfile:
    dest: "{{ file.path }}"
    block: 
      line 1 text....
      line 2 text....
      line 3 text....
    state: present
  check_mode: yes
  register: block_exists
  failed_when: (block_exists | changed)
```

Always `block_exists` is marked as `changed`.

Is `blockinfile`the correct command for this? How can I check if a set of lines exists in a file or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block of the `blockinfile` module is a multiline text marked by starting and ending mark (by default added in a form of a comment).

For your use case using `replace` module in check mode is appropriate:

```
- name: Check content of file
  delegate_to: localhost
  replace:
    path: "{{ file.path }}"
    regexp: |
      line 1 text....
      line 2 text....
      line 3 text....
  check_mode: yes
  register: block_exists
  failed_when: block_exists is changed
```

Comment: I have tried this option, and the task never fails. Does not matter if one line text in the `regexp` is contained in the file or it isn't.

Comment: So you are doing something wrong, because it **does** fail if the multiline text is present with the error: `FAILED! => {"changed": true, "failed_when_result": true, "msg": "1 replacements made"}`.

Comment: Partii karły remember that `regexp` value is a regular expression. You might need to escape certain characters to get a match.

Comment: Ok, I have escaped the characters, but I am going to check the complete test to find some possible missing ones.

Comment: Ok, it was a missing escaped character. Thanks!