# How to skip a template copy in Ansible if the file has a pattern?

Tags: ansible

Trying to only copy an Nginx config file if the destination file does not have a string in it.

I thought this would work:

```yaml
- name: Copy nginx config file
  template:
    src: templates/nginx.conf
    dest: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
    validate: grep -l 'managed by Certbot' %s
```

But this task fails if "managed by Certbot" isn't in the file and stops the playbook run.

How can I just skip the template copy if the destination file already has that pattern? Maybe there's a better way to get the same result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Inspired from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54525651/9401096)*

You can check for the presence of a content in a file using the [`lineinfile` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html) in check mode. Then you can use the result as a condition to your template task. The `default` in the condition is to cope with the case when the file does not exists and the `found` attribute is not in the registered result.

```yaml
---
- name: Check for presence of "managed by Certbot" in file
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
    regexp: ".*# managed by Certbot.*"
    state: absent
  check_mode: yes
  changed_when: false
  register: certbot_managed

- name: Copy nginx config file when not certbot managed
  template:
    src: templates/nginx.conf
    dest: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
  when: certbot_managed.found | default(0) == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`failed_when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-failure) condition and base it on the fail message that `validate` generate — `failed to validate` — to act upon:

```yaml
- name: Copy nginx config file
  template:
    src: templates/nginx.conf
    dest: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
    validate: grep -l 'managed by Certbot' %s
  failed_when: 
    - copy_config_file.failed
    - copy_config_file.msg != 'failed to validate'
  register: copy_config_file
```

<sup>*Note: in `when` and `*_when`, having a list of conditions is like doing `list.0 and list.1 and ...`*</sup>

---

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - copy:
        dest: templates/nginx.conf
        content: "{{ content | default('some random content') }}"

    - copy:
        dest: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
        content: "blank"

    - template:
        src: templates/nginx.conf
        dest: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
        validate: grep -l 'managed by Certbot' %s
      failed_when: 
        - copy_config_file.failed
        - copy_config_file.msg != 'failed to validate'
      register: copy_config_file

    - shell: cat templates/nginx.conf
      register: template_content
      failed_when: false

    - shell: cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
      register: file_content
      failed_when: false

    - debug:
        var: template_content.stdout
    
    - debug:
        var: file_content.stdout
```

1. When run via:

   ```sh
   ansible-playbook play.yml
   ```

   It gives:

   ```
   PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

   TASK [copy] ******************************************************************************************************
   changed: [localhost]

   TASK [copy] ******************************************************************************************************
   changed: [localhost]

   TASK [template] **************************************************************************************************
   ok: [localhost]

   TASK [shell] *****************************************************************************************************
   changed: [localhost]

   TASK [shell] *****************************************************************************************************
   changed: [localhost]

   TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
   ok: [localhost] => {
       "template_content.stdout": "some random content"
   }

   TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
   ok: [localhost] => {
       "file_content.stdout": "blank"
   }

   PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
   localhost                  : ok=7    changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=0     skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
   ```
2. Now, when run with

   ```sh
   ansible-playbook play.yml -e "content='managed by Certbot\nsome other content'"
   ```

   With an extra parameter to modify the content of the template, it gives:

   ```
   PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

   TASK [copy] ******************************************************************************************************
   ok: [localhost]

   TASK [copy] ******************************************************************************************************
   changed: [localhost]

   TASK [template] **************************************************************************************************
   changed: [localhost]

   TASK [shell] *****************************************************************************************************
   changed: [localhost]

   TASK [shell] *****************************************************************************************************
   changed: [localhost]

   TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
   ok: [localhost] => {
       "template_content.stdout": "managed by Certbot\nsome other content"
   }

   TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
   ok: [localhost] => {
       "file_content.stdout": "managed by Certbot\nsome other content"
   }

   PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
   localhost                  : ok=7    changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
   ```