# Ansible "lineinfile": add new line (with PATH=) or append to existing line (with PATH=)

Tags: regex, ansible

I am trying to replace or append a path part to the path definition in /etc/environment on a linux box.

Here's what I have:

```
//all.yml
my_path: "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin"
my_extra_path: "/usr/extra/path"
```

In my role-file:

```
//updatePath.yml
- name: update /etc/environment
  lineinfile:
    dest=/etc/environment
    state=present
    backrefs=yes
    regexp='PATH=({{ my_path }}:?)?({{ my_extra_path }}:?)?(.*)'
    line='PATH={{ my_extra_path }}:{{ my_extra_path }}:\3'
```

Now when I run the role, it works fine updating an existing PATH-line, but not creating duplicates within the line or even duplicate lines. So far so good.

When there is no line with "PATH=" present, I would expect it to add a new one. But it doesn't.

Is my expectation wrong or where lies the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the `backrefs: true` flag, which prevents lineinfile from changing the file if the line does not already exist. From the docs:

> Used with state=present. If set, line can contain backreferences (both
>   positional and named) that will get populated if the regexp matches.
>   This flag changes the operation of the module slightly; insertbefore
>   and insertafter will be ignored, and if the regexp doesn't match
>   anywhere in the file, the file will be left unchanged. If the regexp
>   does match, the last matching line will be replaced by the expanded
>   line parameter.

Since you need to create the line if it does not exist, you should use:

```
- name: Check whether /etc/environment contains PATH
  command: grep -Fxq "PATH=" /etc/environment
  register: checkpath
  ignore_errors: True
  changed_when: False

//updatePath.yml
- name: Add path to /etc/environment
  lineinfile:
    dest=/etc/environment
    state=present
    regexp='^PATH='
    line='PATH={{ my_extra_path }}'
  when: not checkpath.rc == 0

- name: update /etc/environment
  lineinfile:
    dest=/etc/environment
    state=present
    backrefs=yes
    regexp='PATH=({{ my_path }}:?)?({{ my_extra_path }}:?)?(.*)'
    line='PATH={{ my_extra_path }}:{{ my_extra_path }}:\3'
  when: checkpath.rc == 0
```

Comment: No, removing the `backrefs: true` does not work. It creates duplicates if you re-run the ansible role and also it does not add to an existing path, but replace it. To be able to add to the path I need the `backrefs: true`. See the `\3` at the end of `line=`

Comment: Updated my answer to conditionally create the line if it does not exist, but otherwise update the line with backrefs. Backrefs is currently incompatible with creating a line which does not exist, so you need multiple tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Same idea as here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40890850/7231194 or here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40891927/7231194

Steps are:

- Try to replace the line.
- If replace mod change it. Cool, it's over !
- If replace mod doesn't change, add the line

Example

```
# Vars
- name: Set parameters
  set_fact:
    my_path: "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin"
    my_extra_path: "/usr/extra/path"

# Tasks
- name: Try to replace the line if it exists
  replace:
    dest    : /dir/file
    replace : 'PATH={{ my_extra_path }}'
    regexp  : '^PATH=.*'
    backup  : yes
  register  : tryToReplace

# If the line not is here, I add it
- name: Add line
  lineinfile:
    state   : present
    dest    : /dir/file
    line    : '{{ my_extra_path }}'
    regexp  : ''
    insertafter: EOF
  when: tryToReplace.changed == false
```